# Java lambda expression passing method argument in lambda expression

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am trying to use lambda expression in my code but i am getting an error.

```
public static method getInstance(List<String> a, List<String> b, String c){

    result = (a, b, c) -> createConnection(a, b, c);

}
```

i am getting an error like a,b,c are already used and other error is that its expecting java util list but getting lambda paramter.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `method`? Are you trying to return a functional interface that can execute `createConnection()` on demand, with the 3 given parameters? If so, `method` should be some kind of `Supplier`, and you'd do `return () -> createConnection(a, b, c);`

Comment: createConnection method would return map and result type is map but i am trying to pass my method argument into a createconnection through lambda expression. Can you suggest me how i could achieve that??

Comment: It looks like you have a few misunderstandings of Java syntax here. A lambda is generally functionally equivalent to an instance of an anonymous class. If it says that `result` expects `java.util.List` then the RHS must be a list, rather than a lambda. The shadowed fields error (_a, b, and c are already used_) is showing because you're using parameters (_a, b, and c_) in your lambda that already exist in the `getInstance` method signature, and are thus shadowing fields.

Comment: If you want to call `createConnection` and use the result immediately then don't use lambdas -- just call `createConnection` as such: `result = createConnection(a, b, c);`.

Comment: @MikeHill yeah that i know but i am just trying to use lambda expression to achieve the same result.

Comment: @rahul it's impossible to understand what you want to achieve if you don't provide meaningful Java code, and clear explanations.

Comment: @JBNizet i am just trying to call createConnection from getInstance with the same set of parameters which I have for getInstance but using lambda expression instead of oldway. Just to know more about it.

Comment: That's not what lambda expressions are for. Your question makes no sense. To do what you want, all you need is `createConnection(a, b, c)`. Google for "Java lambda tutorial".

Comment: @Mike Hill: these are local variables, not fields. One major difference between local variables and fields is, that shadowing fields is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

the code snippets has reported errors is resonable since it is just a part of lambda expression in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.1), you have duplicated parameter names both in method and lambda expression.

> It is a compile-time error if a receiver **parameter** (§8.4.1) appears in the **FormalParameters** of a lambda expression.

```
public static method getInstance(List<String> a, List<String> b, String c){
     // duplicated parameter names   --->     |               |         |
                                    result = (a,              b,        c) ->
                                             createConnection(a, b, c);

}
```

you should rename the parameter names in labmda expression or in the method signature, for example:

```
public static method getInstance(List<String> a, List<String> b, String c){

    result = (a2, b2, c2) -> createConnection(a2, b2, c2);

}
```